# Simplify $\sqrt{1-\sin^4x}-\sqrt{1-\cos^4x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Simplify
>
> $$\sqrt{1-\sin^4x}-\sqrt{1-\cos^4x}$$

My Try

$$A:=\sqrt{1-\sin^4x}-\sqrt{1-\cos^4x}\\A^2=1-\sin^4x-1+\cos^4x-2\sqrt{(1-\sin^4x)(1-\cos^4x)}\\A^2=\cos^4x-\sin^4x-2\sqrt{(\sin x\cos x)^2(1+\sin^2x)(1+\cos^2x)}$$

Now what ?

Comment: How about this one? $\sqrt{(1-\sin^2 x)(1+\sin^2 x)} - \sqrt{(1-\cos^2 x)(1+\cos^2 x)} = |\cos x|\sqrt{1+\sin^2 x} - |\sin x| \sqrt{1+\cos^2 x}.$

Comment: Interestingly, this is almost equal to $1-4/\pi|x|$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-\sin^{4} x} - \sqrt{1-\cos^{4} x} & = \sqrt{(1-\sin^{2} x)(1+\sin^{2} x)} - \sqrt{(1-\cos^{2} x)(1+\cos^{2} x)} \\
 & = \sqrt{(cos^{2} x)(1+\sin^{2} x)} - \sqrt{(sin^{2} x)(1+\cos^{2} x)} \\ 
 & = \lvert \cos x\rvert\sqrt{1+\sin^{2} x} - \lvert \sin x\rvert\sqrt{1+\cos^{2} x} \\
\end{align}

Comment: I suggest you to first see comments and after that post your answer!

Comment: @Amin235 Ohhh, you right. I didn't see the comments. My bad

Comment: For the first time, no problem. I suggest to improve your question to find a better simple closed-form. For example, multiply your last results by the equation $\frac{\lvert \cos x\rvert\sqrt{1+\sin^{2} x} + \lvert \sin x\rvert\sqrt{1+\cos^{2} x}}{\lvert \cos x\rvert\sqrt{1+\sin^{2} x} +\lvert \sin x\rvert\sqrt{1+\cos^{2} x}}$, maybe useful.